# How to delay mounting swap after boot?

Tags: 15.04, swap

`systemd-analyze blame` showed me that mounting swap took 9.125 seconds. I cannot disable it because I'm using hibernation a lot. But I'd like to delay mounting it for 5 minutes after boot. Is that possible with `systemd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an **executable** script with the swapon command:

```
#!/bin/sh
swapon /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

Comment out the swap line in `/etc/fstab` and add something like this to `/etc/crontab`:

```
@reboot         root    at now +3 minutes -f /usr/bin/swapon.sh
```